# Sharing non-serializable object between multiple processes in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I have an Object which is not serializable. I want to share it between more than two java processes.
How can I do that?

(I wouldn't like to use transient because I need non-serializable fields in my object.)

**EDIT:**
Java processes are local and run in one system.

Comment: How heavyweight is this object? Better yet, what's the object? In general, if you have something heavy that needs to be accessed by multiple processes, you set it up as a service that accepts requests that allow for modification and querying of the object's state.

Comment: Can I use shared memory or message queue or pipe?

Comment: @Misha , Service isn't good solution. One process is only provider and another is consumer. Modification and querying of the object's state has to be done only by consumer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to serialize a Java object between two processes.  One that is commonly used these days is JSON.  Two popular frameworks are [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

The nice thing about JSON is that it is well-understood, plays well with HTTP, maps well to other languages such as Javascript, Ruby, Python, etc, and it is fairly easy to ready which helps a lot with debugging.  We have been using Jackson for a number of years and are pretty happy with its power and speed, although sometimes it can be overly complex.  Others are quite happy with GSON.

If you are looking to optimize the payload on the network, and HTTP is not an issue, you can look at binary mechanisms like Google Protocol Buffers

Comment: MY OBJECT ISN'T SERIALIZABLE!